# Are there any historic armed combat sports that don't simulate sword-fighting (other than jousting)?

Tags: weapons, medieval, history, combat, martial-arts

I'm focusing on a medieval warfare setting similar to Fire Emblem, and the tiresome abundance of swords has me thinking about alternative weapons to shine a spotlight on. I'm also thinking about the visual aspects of combat which is why I'm curious about combat sports with history, culture, and plenty of source material to study.

I've tried looking online and found quite a few swordplay/stick-fighting sports, which I'm trying to avoid, as well as jousting and then more modern sports like paintball. The latter-most example obviously doesn't fit with the era. Basically I just want to know if there are any examples out there. The sport and weapons involved don't necessarily need to be historical, but no magic, and the weapons should be possible for the era, like wood and steel. I would prefer historical examples to fictional ones though.

**EDIT** for clarity

- Combat  - people hitting each other, or at least trying to.
- Armed Combat - people hitting each other with arms(weapons)

I was trying to ask about a way for people to practice killing others(for when  they need to), without killing their practice partners or being killed themselves, like boxing, fencing, etc. I used the term combat sport, which seemed to confuse some people, because sports have rules and scoring in place of killing. Maybe there should be a hyphen somewhere in armed combat sport.

**The comment about kung-fu seems like what I was looking for.** I didn't know there were armed variants.

Comment: Archery comes to mind. Long history, well established techniques..etc. I'm not aware of a variant where participants shot at anything other than stationary targets or game, but its conceivable it could have safely been transformed into a contact sport with the right equipment and preparation

Comment: To avoid being closed as off topic I suggest rephrasing to ask if there are any historic forms of non-sword combat that could be turned into sports.

Comment: Google martial arts, then ignore the sword stuff, and you'll have hundreds of weapons. Sticks, staves, pole-arms, knives, nunchucks, the list goes on. Many ALSO have swords, but many of the weapons are not swords. Are you looking for something more specific? European only? southeast asian? Modern, but with an ancient feel?

Comment: Kung Fu. It's older than most sports and many styles are practiced with spears, staves, maces and even a ball on a chain (and swords too, but you don't want those).

Answer (score 3):

Depends on what you consider to be combat.

Capture The Flag is a game of sneaking, reconnaissance, and athleticism.

Chess is a game of tactics and strategy. There are many board games both current and historic that simulate combat, tactics or strategy. The Romans played a game called Ludus Latrunculorum that simulated moving soldiers around a field. Today we play Risk and Axis and Allies.

The Native Americans did Counting Coup, which is not really a game but encouraged valorous non-combat actions in the face of a combative enemy. These were things such as tagging an enemy and getting away uninjured, or stealing their horses.

The Mesoamericans played "Mesoamerican Ball" which is a game that we know exists but don't really understand the rules for. One theory is that the game was a proxy for warfare, where tribes in disagreement would play each other and the victorious tribe would get their way. It also seems like this game sometimes involved ritual human sacrifice as well.

Arguably any team game teaches a group of people to act as a cohesive unit and thus has military applications.

Comment: Pretty much all modern wargames (and, more distantly, roleplaying games) trace their ancestry back to Kriegsspiel, a training tool used by the Prussian army. So while some of them may be of dubious accuracy, there's definitely precedent for using wargames to simulate and teach real strategy.

Comment: All the Olympics! There you run, throw stuff, fight. Shotting with the bow WAS using a weapon, same with the javelin.

Answer (score 2):

**Polo.**

[image: persian polo]

> Polo is perhaps the oldest team sport, although the exact origins of
>   the game are unknown. It was probably first played by nomadic warriors
>   over two thousand years ago but the first recorded tournament was in
>   600 B.C. (between the Turkomans and the Persians – the Turkomans were
>   victorious). ...
>
> Played on horse back, in the Middle Ages it was used in the training
>   of cavalry across the East (from Japan to Constantinople, and was
>   played almost as a miniature battle...
>   https://www.historic-uk.com/CultureUK/The-Origins-of-Polo/

The weapon here is not the mallet, but the horse.  You cannot really kill or maim each other in a game but you can use your skill with your horse to outmaneuver your opponent and win.